# GXT - Warning in AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gxt, gwt-ext

I recently started reading about and tried working on `GXT.`
Few days back, I tried to run a simple `GxtGridExample` code.

Source code : [GxtGridExample](http://zawoad.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-create-simple-grid-using-gxtext.html)

It did compile and run properly.
But when I tried running it in web browser giving some url like  e.g `http://www.localhost:8888/` , it gave me the following warning.

---

### ***`[WARN] Can not serve /GxtGridExample.html directly.  You need to include it in <static-files> in your appengine-web.xml.`***

---

and when I tried re-running the code by including it in the < static-files >,it gave me something new to add in the same files.

What does that warning exactly mean ?
If I am not able to present my question properly,excuse me for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine wants to know which files are static, so it can optimize by serving them from different servers. You do not have to specify each file individually, you can use patterns:

```
<static-files>
        <include path="/**.png" />
        <include path="/**.css" />
        <include path="/**.html" />
        <include path="/**.js" />
</static-files>
```

See more info at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files